# order of operations with addOperationWithBlock

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsoperationqueue

I am facing some weird results with `addOperationWithBlock`.

My function looks something like this:

```
-(void) myFunction{
   NSLog(@"VISITED");

 ..



  for (NSDictionary *Obj in myObjects)
  {
    [operationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^(void){
         MyObject* tmp = [self tediousFunction:Obj];
         // threadTempObjects is member NSMutableArray
         [self.threadTempObjects addObject:tmp];
         NSLog(@"ADDED");
    }];
  }

 [operationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^(void){
       [self.myArray addObjectsFromArray:self.threadTempObjects];

       for(myObject *myObj in self.myArray)
       {
            // MAIN_QUEUE
            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^(void) {
                [self updateUI:myObj];
            }];
       }
   }];



   [operationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^(void){
       [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^(void) {
             [self filterResults];
       }];
   }];

}
```

My dictionary contains 4 values, and therefore the ADDED shows in the log 4 times.
**BUT**, 
when I check inside the **filterResults**, I see that there are only **2** objects inside **myArray**. Meaning that the 4 times the operationQueue was called did not end before the filterResults operation was called (although it was added later!)

I thought that the operationQueue is serial and that I can count on it that when I add an operation it would be added right after the last operation. 
So it is weird that only 2 operations are in the array in the aftermath. 
What am I missing?  Thanks

Comment: You are using 2 different queues here, please share their configuration code so we may verify they are indeed serial (serial would mean `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of 1)

Comment: You might be confusing with [GCD operation queue](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html).

Comment: Your operation queue is only serial if you make it serial.

Comment: initialization: operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]; Is the operation Queue not functioning as a queue ? Do operations happen all together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you shared as your initialisation code we can learn that `operationQueue` is not serial, meaning it will execute operations, and allocate thread up until the system set maximal thread count (same as with GCD).
This mean that operations added to `operationQueue` are running in parallel.
To run them serially set the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to 1.
Try something like:

```
__block __weak id weakSelf = self;
[operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];

for (NSDictionary *Obj in myObjects)
{
    [operationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
        MyObject* tmp = [weakSelf tediousFunction:Obj];
        // threadTempObjects is member NSMutableArray
        [weakSelf.threadTempObjects addObject:tmp];
        NSLog(@"ADDED");
    }];
}

[operationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
    [weakSelf.myArray addObjectsFromArray:weakSelf.threadTempObjects];

    for(myObject *myObj in weakSelf.myArray)
    {
        // MAIN_QUEUE
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^(void) {
            [weakSelf updateUI:myObj];
        }];
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^(void) {
            [weakSelf filterResults];
        }];
    }
}];
```

But, this is equal (or even less efficient) to simply:

```
__block __weak id weakSelf = self;
[operationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
    for (NSDictionary *Obj in myObjects) {
        MyObject* tmp = [weakSelf tediousFunction:Obj];
        // threadTempObjects is member NSMutableArray
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^(void) {
            [weakSelf updateUI:tmp];
        }];
        [weakSelf.myArray addObject:tmp];
        NSLog(@"ADDED");
    }
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^(void) {
        [weakSelf filterResults];
     }];
}];
```

Comment: Hi Dan, in your first example you do this : `operationQueue addOperationWithBlock `. What if in this block we will also have: `operationQueue addOperationWithBlock`  (new addOperationWithBlock block), is it ok? I can't find information about that. Or it's better to avoid it and just remove second operation block?

Comment: @flinth This should also work for nested `addOperationWithBlock`